# How can I know the composition of a gas pocket entrapped in a plastic sheet?

Tags: spectroscopy, plastics

I have a 1 mm thick plastic sheet, the plastic is not opaque.

Some gas pockets, I would say some *bubbles*, are inside the sheet; the size of the bubbles is about 1 mm.

What methods are available to know the composition of the gas that is inside the pockets?

Methods can destroy the sample.

Comment: Gas chromatography, possibly even GC/MS. Sample a bubble using a small syringe and put the sample through a GC/MS set up to identify common gases.